# Dynamically explode columns in Pandas row

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, pandas, dataframe

I have a `DataFrame` with multiple columns per row which need to be split into a new rows per column

The `DataFrame` currently (shortened down) looks like this

```
|---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|institution_short_name |interest_paid1 |interest_paid2 |product_detail_value_min |term_01m_value |term_02y_value |term_03m_value |
|---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|One                    |Z              |Q              |2000                     |0.50           |0.75           |0.75           |
|One                    |Z              |Q              |5000                     |0.50           |3.65           |3.75           |
|One                    |M              |M              |20000                    |Nan            |3.65           |Nan            | 
|---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
```

For each `term` column, e.g i would like to extract the 01m, 02y, 03m from the name of the column as well as the value for that row under that column and explode it like the following:

```
|----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|institution_short_name |interest_paid1 |interest_paid2 |product_detail_value_min |Term            |Value  |
|----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|One                    |Z              |Q              |2000                     |01m             |0.5    |
|One                    |Z              |Q              |2000                     |02y             |3.75   |
|One                    |Z              |Q              |2000                     |03m             |0.75   |
|One                    |Z              |Q              |5000                     |01m             |0.5    |
|One                    |Z              |Q              |5000                     |02y             |3.65   |
|One                    |Z              |Q              |5000                     |03m             |3.75   |
|One                    |M              |M              |20000                    |02y             |3.65   |
|----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
```

I am not asking for a complete solution, just something to get me started. Thanks!

Comment: what is `explode` in pandas?

Comment: @Prateek: [`Series.explode` is new in 0.25](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.25/whatsnew/v0.25.0.html#series-explode-to-split-list-like-values-to-rows), it splits "list-likes" (e.g. lists of objects, string lists) into multiple rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check [wide_to_long](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.wide_to_long.html)

```
pd.wide_to_long(df.repalce('Nan',np.nan),['term'],i=['institution_short_name','interest_paid1','interest_paid2','product_detail_value_min'],j='Term',suffix='\\w+').reset_index().dropna()
```

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I am looking for

Comment: @PhilBaines yw : -) , one tips `suffix='\\w+'` this is most confusion part , I used to have problem with it :-)

Comment: @PhilBaines if this what you need would you mind accept it ?